# copyright symbol is not not rendered in browser

Tags: mjml

I am using this code of snippet

```
       <mj-text align="center">
        © 2018  or &copy; or &#169;
      </mj-text>
```

and  this code printing  unnecessary  Â ,like this Â© .  how can i print copyright symbol in mjml ?

Comment: It seems to be an encoding issue. If you try it online, [it renders correctly](https://mjml.io/try-it-live/ryOE9dqcG). If you add `<mj-head charset="utf-8"></mj-head>`, does that help?

Comment: it's still not working for me. again printing same.

Comment: i solved this issue like this .
<mj-text align="center">
     <img width="10px" 
          height="10px"
          src="http://images/copyright_icon.png">
      </img>
       2018.
</mj-text>

Answer (score 2):

You can try it like this:

```
<mj-text align="center">Copyright &#160;&#169;&#160 </mj-text>
```

This works fine with mjml 4.0. .

Answer (score 0):

I use the MJML app and have no problems in using `&#169;`